# Form, input text to each other: 50%, gaps

Tags: html, css

I have the following form:

http://jsfiddle.net/LwJBz/

```
    <div id="contact">
        <div id="col2">
            <h3>Üzenetet küldök</h3>
            <form>
                <div>
<input type="text" name="Nev" placeholder="Név" /><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email cím" /><br /><input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefonszám" />
                    <textarea placeholder="Üzenet"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Küldés" />
                    <img style="visibility: hidden;" src="{'place.gif'|lws_img}" alt="place icon" width="10" height="16" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

#contact #col2 input,textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 61px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #434343;
    font-family: rock;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contact #col2 input[name=Nev]
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#contact #col2 input[name=Email]
{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
#contact #col2 textarea
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 143px;
}
#contact #col2 input[type="submit"]
{
    width: 156px;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: #EE4135;
    color: white;
}

body
{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I need to have a gap between "Nev" and "Email" input field, but I have no idea. I was having fun with negative margins, with less success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the border-box property doesn't inculde margins, I wrapped the inputs in divs and applied padding to them so the gaps are all the same and fixed size.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/LwJBz/46/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="col2">
         <h3>Üzenetet küldök</h3>

        <form>
            <div>
                <div class="float">
                    <input type="text" name="Nev" placeholder="Név" />
                </div>
                <div class="float">
                    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email cím" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefonszám" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea placeholder="Üzenet"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Küldés" />
                </div>
                <img style="visibility: hidden;" src="{'place.gif'|lws_img}" alt="place icon" width="10" height="16" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact #col2 input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 61px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #434343;
    font-family: rock;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
form div {
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.float {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#contact #col2 textarea {
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 143px;
}
#contact #col2 input[type="submit"] {
    width: 156px;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: #EE4135;
    color: white;
}
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I dont think so :S when its getting shrinking, it loses its aspects-ratio

Comment: what do you mean by loosing aspect ratio? both inputs have the same width whatever the width of the screen.

Comment: the "nev" and "email" is getting more closer, while the other fields keep the spacing

Comment: @JohnSmith would this suit you? http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/LwJBz/21/ all the "gaps" between the elements resize and are all equal.

Comment: but it should remain fixed :)

Comment: @JohnSmith ok I found a solution for you : http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/LwJBz/46/  As the border-box property doesn't inculde margins, I wrapped the inputs in divs and applied padding to them so the gaps are all the same and fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the code with this... then it will be working  you can change margin left.

```
#contact #col2 input[name=Email]
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        margin-left:50px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this in your css:

```
#contact #col2 input[name="Nev"] {
 width:49%;
}

#contact #col2 input[name="Email"] {
 width:49%;
}
```

Comment: I dont think so :S when its getting shrinking, it loses its aspects-ratio

Comment: you can do the same for other field too.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just a smaller percentage value for the fields?

```
#contact #col2 input[name=Nev]
{
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#contact #col2 input[name=Email]
{
    width: 49%;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I dont think so :S when its getting shrinking, it loses its aspects-ratio